# Android Design- Content Provider plus real time information- How to display?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

Here's something interesting- How do I display information both from my content provider, and some real-time data from the web (which I don't want to save to my content provider?).

1.CursorLoader and CursorAdapter won't do IMO since I don't want to save the information to my content provider.

2.AsyncTask and updating the view in onPostExecute won't work, since right now I am displaying information from my content provider through cursorAdapter etc. and since the screen itself is an AdapterView subclass, when the loading is finished, the view might belong to some other element (recycled)

3.Service won't do for the same reason as #2 (and besides that, in this case, the background thread is coupled with the UI, so that doesn't seem like a natural solution).

**********Optional specific details starting from here if the picture isn't clear******

Say that I have some app which allows users to follow stocks.
I have a content provider, that at the path content://whatever.my.package.name/follows
has some information about which stock the user is following, whether or not it was sent to my server already (so it does have already some 'real time' data displaying through it), the parameters the user is interested in following, etc.

When displaying this information, I want to include some real time information from the web. I already have the necessary method implemented, but I can't think of a natural solution (see above). In particular, the real time data certainly cannot be saved on the same path (/follows) since this isn't a natural part of what I have in mind when I am thinking about the object "follow",but I do want to present the real time information about the stock, and it does relate to the follow presented on the screen (for example, a follow includes a start price, so we want to present the change from that start price to the real time price of the same stock etc).

I'm can't think of a good design I could use, so help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing that stops you from using the content provider is that you don't want to store the informations in it, then don't store it. Remember that a provider is just some abstraction above some data source. Nobody is going to stop you from using a in memory sqlite database for storing the live data.

Then you have two data sources and can build relations on them for displaying purposes like with sqlites [attach_database](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) or in code. Of course the live data is gone as soon as the provider is shut down so you must be able to handle that case.

---

EDIT

Hmm, ok. So touching the provider is a no go. You said the views are adapter views. How about using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) or something similar to fetch the data in the adapter itself and cache it there. Whenever a view is requested (i.e in 'onBindView' when using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)) check the adapter cache for the data. If it does not exist or is outdated start fetching the data. When the request returns notify the adapter that the dataset changed. It then would start requesting views again making the next cache probe a hit. If you are fetching the data for each item in the cursor try to pass the index/position of the item to the request so that you can notify the adapter that a specific item has changed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your answer...even if I were to store the live data in a sqlite database,it wouldn't be on the same table, or the same path as the follow, as the live data is not part of a follow as I see it. So, let's say that I store the data in some other table (or file and then used attach_database). How would I then present the data? that's the question. with just one table/path to my content provider, I have a very convenient way in the form of a cursor loader + cursor adapter+loader. If I have more than one data source, what is the most convenient way in that case?

Comment: I was thinking of including the live data in the cursor returned from the query to 'follow'. So whenever the app queries that particular uri I would also query the live database (within the provider) for some results and then include it in the cursor returned. Ether with an custom cursor or by merging the values of both results in a [MatrixCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html). That way the ui can receive both informations for display.

Comment: The problem is that that breaks the encapsulation of the content provider, after all  the data of what the user is following, and the live data are different. We don't want the path /follow to contain data which is not the 'follow' itself. I could use some awkward path within the provider such as content://whateverpackgename/followwithlivedata, but that seems a bit awkward. Is there a better way?